# Odoo Session Expired Randomly

Tags: python, session, server, odoo, odoo-11

i keep getting the message ''Odoo Session Expired'' randomly. I have no idea why. I restarted my local instance/server but this didn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: When use domain filter based on host, this cause to plenty of users across the world.

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when you run multiple instances of odoo in local and browse from same browser.

Comment: Or a you restart a single Odoo instance with multiple tabs open in the same browser.

Comment: Is there way to fix this. If you want to debug two enviroments

Comment: You can try private mode or use another browser for same.

Comment: That's not solution, its official cause, even we add report.url, this keep happing with multi-domain filter